# Edit file in ms-dos

Tags: windows, apache, cmd, xampp

Can this be done?

Basically I work on multiple projects using xampp, and I like `http://localhost` to be the project root ( rather than `http://localhost/project_name/` )

Problem is, i have to open the httpd.conf file in the apache folder, change the document root, then restart apache!

I was wondering if this could be done in ms-dos?

say I write a batch file that:

```
opens the file,
finds the document root,
changes it,
stop apache,
start apache
```

Then all i would need to do is open the cmd prompt, and write:

`http_change.bat new_project_name`

Problem is, I only know basic ms-dos and examples and tuition on the web are surprising hard to understand!

**EDIT**

I'm Really struggling with this so im offering a bounty.

so far i've tried:

```
for /f "eol=# tokens=* delims=*" %%a in (httpd.conf) do echo %%a
```

this successfully reads the file, but then i tried

```
for /f "eol=# tokens=* delims=*" %%a in (httpd.conf) do (
    echo %%a
)
```

and that worked. then

```
for /f "eol=# tokens=* delims=*" %%a in (httpd.conf) do (
    set line=%%a
    echo %line%
)
```

and that failed... it just echoed "ECHO is off." which makes me assume the it isnt setting the line variable...

my plan was to check each line to see if the first 12 characters == "DocumentRoot" and if they do, rather than saving the line to a new file, i modify the line using sting manipulation and save that instead...

Comment: Is a vbscript solution acceptable?

Comment: i don't know, can i use vb on my ms-dos commandline? i have windows 7, I think id rather pure ms-dos

Comment: vbscript is a scripting language (not to be confused with vb6/vb.net); its interpreters are bundled with windows, you do not have to install anything to run that script.

Comment: Sorry, MS-DOS does not exists as part of windows from Windows 2000.Please call it windows command line instead.

Comment: sorry. but i didnt know, becuase ive never been told, but now i have. thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're causing yourself unnecessary grief by trying to edit the configuration file.  Here's a better idea:

- Remove the `DocumentRoot` setting from your `httpd.conf` file.  Replace it with an `Include` directive, something like:

  ```
  Include \path\to\documentroot.conf
  ```
- Now instead of editing a file you simple replace the `documentroot.conf` file, which contains a single line of the form:

  ```
  DocumentRoot \path\to\my\documentroot
  ```

And here's another idea:

You can pass Apache configuration options on the command line with the `-C` directive (or `-c`, depending on whether you want your directive applied before (`-C`) or after (`-c`) Apache reads its configuration files).  So as with the previous idea, remove the DocumentRoot directive from your `httpd.conf`, and then when you restart `httpd`, start it like this:

```
httpd -C 'DocumentRoot \path\to\my\documentroot'
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped!  If you're happy with this solution it would be great if you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how to:
`1. find the directory with batch,
or, 2. start/stop apache`
but I *can* tell you how to edit it.
If you use XP or before, use
`edit <drive:\path\file.ext>`,
And if you use anything 64bit, or Vista or later, use
`copy con <drive:\path\file.ext>`
becuase the 16-bit `edit` application was removed from 64-bit versions of Windows.