# Automatic change root directory of Apache

Tags: windows, apache, batch-file, xampp

¡Hola, amigos!

I want to automate the process of setting the Apache's root directory with a batch file (Just because, there's not a good reason but saving like 3 seconds of my life). To do this, I need to replace lines #244 and #245 with %cd%

First, I've created a PATH to the batch file, so in cmd I write "> serveThis" and it runs the .bat file. That works fine.

Now, the tricky part (for me), the Batch file (From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395013/batch-edit-specified-line-in-text-file)):

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL

SET "file=C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf"
SET /a Line#ToSearch=244
SET Replacement = DocumentRoot "%CD%"

(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
    SET "Line=%%b"
    IF %%a equ %Line#ToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement%"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    ECHO(!Line!
    ENDLOCAL
))>"%file%.new"
TYPE "%file%.new"


SET /a Line#ToSearch=245
SET Replacement = DocumentRoot "%CD%"

(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
    SET "Line=%%b"
    IF %%a equ %Line#ToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement%"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    ECHO(!Line!
    ENDLOCAL
))>"%file%.new"
TYPE "%file%.new"
```

tbh I don't completely understand what's happening, but It doesn't work. Any idea?

I've aldo found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906189/edit-file-in-ms-dos), but I didn't understand.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is quite a poor description of what is happening and what you actually want to happen, so please be more specific... anyway, you read the original file, replace line #244 and store it to a new file; then you read the original file again, replace line #245 and overwrite the new file; I guess that is not what you want...

Comment: it deletes all the content in httpd.conf

Comment: Hmm, hard to believe, the file `httpd.conf` is only read but never written in your code... nevertheless, there is one more problem in your code: `set Replacement = DocumentRoot "%CD%"`; you need to remove the spaces around the `=` sign; at the moment, they become part of the variable name and value...